# Using tuples to remove duplicate coordinates from a list in VBA

Tags: python, vba, duplicates

I have two arrays filled with X and Y values. The values are pulled from text boxes the user fills.

These values (x1,y1), (y1,y2), (x_nth, y_nth) are plotted, where n is the number of points in my arrays.

**I want to run through these coordinate pairs and find the ones that overlap each other**. Once I find an overlapping point identified then I can change the duplicate(s) marker size to be bigger so the reader can see how often a point is repeated. Right now I just want to accomplish the former.

I’m not familiar with VBA I work mainly in Python. Below is my example code that works in python.

```
x = [1,2,2,4,5,5,5]
y = [1,3,3,4,5,5,5]
pts = []
for i in range(len(x)):
    cX = x[i]
    cY = y[i]
    if (cX, cY) in pts:
        print("duplicate")
        print(cX, cY)
        #plot this point on scatter
        #increase marker size for this particular point
    else:
        pts.append((cX, cY))
print(pts)
```

Output

```
Duplicate
2 3
Duplicate
5 5
Duplicate
5 5
[(1,1), (2, 3), (4,4), (5,5)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just threw this together real quick, but it does the job. Python does a better job working with data than vba (more data types like lists and tuples). There are a few ways to make this happen, I just chose to use a 2 dimensional array.

```
Dim array_Tuple() As Variant, i As Integer, xsplit, ysplit
Dim sLength As Integer, x As String, y As String, v
Dim bool As Boolean

x = "1,2,2,4,5,5,5"
y = "1,3,3,4,5,5,5"

xsplit = Split(x, ",")
ysplit = Split(y, ",")
count = 0

On Error Resume Next
For i = 0 To UBound(xsplit)
bool = True

    For j = 0 To count
        If xsplit(i) = array_Tuple(1, j) And ysplit(i) = array_Tuple(2, j) Then
            If Not err.Number <> 0 Then
                bool = False
            End If
            err.Clear
        End If
    Next

If bool Then
    count = count + 1
    ReDim Preserve array_Tuple(1 To 2, 1 To count)
    array_Tuple(1, count) = xsplit(i)
    array_Tuple(2, count) = ysplit(i)

    Debug.Print array_Tuple(1, count) & "," & array_Tuple(2, count)
End If

Next
On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: Can I have a little more explanation on how it works? What is the purpose of having the on Error Resume Next? Is it just good practice to include this?

Comment: What is the purpose of having the on Error Resume Next? : In this case there is no built in function to check if our new values are already in the array. So, the first time we pass through this it will error (there is nothing in array_Tuple). This will just continue on to the next line. Again there is probably a better way just something that works.

Comment: Can I have a little more explanation on how it works?: We are looping through the length of the 'list' and adding x & y to an array. First we loop through the entire current array so we don't duplicate values, if we pass the test then the values area added.